# Error When Submitting Asp.Net MVC Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

**ISSUE**

I am trying to submit an asp.net mvc form and I get the following error.  When the page initially loads it hits the GridData method successfully. If I click the Submit button in the view below, I get the following error.

**ERROR**

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'page' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult GridData(System.String, System.String, Int32, Int32)' in 'HunterEdge.Web.Controllers.DataController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

**PARTIAL VIEW: This is the view data I'm trying to submit**

```
@model HunterEdge.Web.Models.HarvestDataFilter

@using (Html.BeginForm("GridData", "Data"))
{
    <div style=" width:300px; height:550px; float:left">
         html removed for brevity

       <input type="submit" value="Search" style=" margin-left:110px" />
   </div> 
}
```

**CONTROLER ACTION METHOD I'M TRYING TO GET FORM DATA TO**

```
 public JsonResult GridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, HarvestDataFilter filter)
    {                        

        var results = (from a in db.t_harvest_statistics_elk
                        where a.year == "2008" && a.unit_number == 1
                        orderby a.id
                        select new { a.id, a.year, a.unit_number, a.total_hunters, a.bulls, a.cows }).ToList(); 

        int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int pageSize = rows;
        int totalRecords = results.Count();   
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

        var pageResults = results.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);           

        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = (
                from pageResult in pageResults
                select new
                {
                    id = pageResult.id,
                    cell = new[] { 
                                    pageResult.year.ToString(),
                                    "Add",
                                    pageResult.unit_number.ToString(),                                         
                                    pageResult.total_hunters.ToString(),
                                    pageResult.bulls.ToString(),
                                    "add",
                                    pageResult.cows.ToString(),
                                    "add",
                                    "add",
                                    "add"

            }
                }).ToArray()
        };
        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should filter the grid data in another way. The usage of `Html.BeginForm` is the wrong way. Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5501644/315935) and use either the [filter toolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) or [advanced searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching). If you do decide to use you custom `<input>` field you should use `postData` with the property defined as function (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935)) and use `.trigger("reloadGrid", [{page: 1}])` to send the searching request to the controller. In the case you should add new parameter which corresponds the property name in the `postData` to the list of parameters of `GridData`.